# slick slider 1 image moves down

Tags: reactjs, slick.js

I've been trying for a while now, but can't find a solution by myself.

Basically, in my slick slider, I have 6 images which I would like to animate on slick in and before next slick (after clicking arrows/dotts). there are 2 problems; one as you can see in the [screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF13o.jpg) one image moves down if i show 5 images, if i show 6 images then first image smaller than others.

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import './trendslider.css'


export default class CenterMode extends Component {
  
  imageClick = () =>{
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>THIS IS TRENDING PAGE</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  render () {
      const settings = {
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "10px",
        slidesToShow: 5,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        // dots: true,
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
              arrows: false,
              centerMode: true,
              centerPadding: '40px',
              slidesToShow: 3
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              arrows: false,
              centerMode: true,
              centerPadding: '40px',
              slidesToShow: 1
            }
          }
        ]
      };
      
      const imgs = [
      'images/01.jpg', 
      'images/02.jpg', 
      'images/03.jpg', 
      'images/04.jpg', 
      'images/05.jpg',
      'images/06.jpg'
    ];
      
      const renderSlides = () => 
      imgs.map(num => (
        <img className='trending-img' src = {num} alt="" on onClick={this.imageClick}></img>
      ));
  
    return (
      <div className = "App">
        <h4 className = 'header'>Trending</h4>
        <section class="center slider">
          <div>
            <Slider {...settings}>
              {renderSlides()}
            </Slider>
            
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the css. You have a margin between the images so you definitely have parameters in these classes (or one of them):

```
.slick-list {
  margin: xx;
}
.slick-slide {
  margin: xx;
}
```

Comment these lines and add this instead :

```
.slick-slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slick-list {
  position: relative;
  display: block !important;
  width: 100%;
}
.slick-slide div {
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.slick-slide img {
  width: calc(100% - 10px) !important;
}
```

PS : You can delete the 'center' parameters from settings

```
centerMode: true,
centerPadding: '10px',
```

Demo : [Here](https://react-gfjpfa.stackblitz.io/)

Code : [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gfjpfa)

Comment: thank you for the response but still same.

Comment: Check my edited answer with demo. You will see that there is no issue with slick carousel

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem. It wasn't easy without your css (next time share it) ... I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks dude. it is fixed after I changed my CSS as u showed. appreciated.